# How can I get the GC class histogram programmatically

Tags: java, class, garbage-collection, histogram

I would like to get the same result of the follow command programmatically:

```
jcmd <pid> GC.class_histogram | grep 'sun.util'

 728:            27           2592  sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date
 800:            44           2112  sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache$CacheEntry
 816:            36           2016  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
1169:            22            880  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Key
```

...

I already searched for many answers, but none of the found is clear and do what I want, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The follow code shows the same result:

```
import javax.management.MBeanException;
import javax.management.ReflectionException;

import com.sun.management.DiagnosticCommandMBean;

import sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class ClassHistogram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MBeanException, ReflectionException {
        DiagnosticCommandMBean dcmd = ManagementFactoryHelper.getDiagnosticCommandMBean();

        String[] emptyStringArgs = {};
        Object[] dcmdArgs = { emptyStringArgs };
        String[] signature = { String[].class.getName() };
        System.out.println(dcmd.invoke("gcClassHistogram", dcmdArgs, signature));
    }

}
```

Reference from the available commands: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

Comment: This was great, but I didn't get it to work (J17 and J21) - the invocation wasn't happy with some of the types. This variant however worked out-of-the-box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273493/39334

Answer (score 1):

The [jcmd manpage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jcmd.html) covers this.

> To invoke diagnostic commands from a remote machine or with different identifiers, you can use the com.sun.management.DiagnosticCommandMBean interface. For more information about the DiagnosticCommandMBean interface, see the API documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/DiagnosticCommandMBean.html

Comment: Thank you for the reference, based on this I found my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently developed a small memory profiler that will get the GC.histogram and generate charts and a table.

And the simplest solution I found was to connect to the VM:

https://github.com/check-leak/check-leak/blob/7d45764965400e2a280b9cb9b82f97b177abf321/check-leak/src/main/java/io/github/checkleak/core/RemoteCheckLeak.java#L199-L209

```
   public void connect(String id) throws Exception {
      machine = VirtualMachine.attach("" + id);
      if (!(machine instanceof HotSpotVirtualMachine)) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect to HotSpotVirtualMachine. Type is " + machine.getClass());
      }
      hotSpotVirtualMachine = (HotSpotVirtualMachine) machine;
   }

   public InputStream execute(String command) throws Exception {
      return hotSpotVirtualMachine.executeJCmd(command);
   }
```

in the above code you can call execute(