# How to track and monitoring, jvm class size

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Yesterday my JVM application was broken due to high CPU usage, when checking the root cause this is because GC stop the world. The GC require more time to clean up the memory, this is because I introduce new LRU cache at the app. So my question is:

Is there any way to track how big memory group by JVM class? For example, I have 3 classes, *Foo*, *Bar*, *Baz*.

I want to know how big memory used by each class at run time.

I have a Datadog account, so I plan to use tools to send those metrics to Datadog.

Comment: I suppose you already know JMC (JDK Mission Control)? See [5 Real-time JMX Monitoring](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/doc/JDMUG/real-time-jmx-monitoring.htm)

Comment: That said, questions asking for tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `jcmd` command line tool

```
jcmd <PID> GC.class_histogram | less
```

As an example of running this on my simple Clojure application:

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name (module)
-------------------------------------------------------
   1:         40131        2944504  [B (java.base@14.0.1)
   2:         38953        1666008  [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.base@14.0.1)
   3:          7610         961920  java.lang.Class (java.base@14.0.1)
   4:         36134         867216  java.lang.String (java.base@14.0.1)
   5:          2353         762216  [I (java.base@14.0.1)
   6:         25076         601824  clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap$BitmapIndexedNode
   7:         13950         446400  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node (java.base@14.0.1)
...
```

Comment: `jcmd` is like a hidden gem!

Comment: oh waw this is what I wanted, but any libraries that I can use to get same result ?

Comment: @DavidAsync here's the answer using `DiagnosticCommandMBean` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325951/how-can-i-get-the-gc-class-histogram-programmatically